# Can one activity use two xmls?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to use one activity and have it use 2 or more xmls.

I need the activity to change resource images from two different xmls,

```
private TextView hinttext;
private TextView[] txtv = new TextView[16];
```

hinttext is one xml that has one picture in it
and the array txtv holds other pictures.

When I try to change txtv, no problem what so ever, but when I try to change hinttext resource image I get:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference

And I didn't manage to find anything relating to this. Any suggestions?

Comment: textviews hold text, not images. Activities as a general rule have one dynamic source (java) and one static source (xml). You may want to consider fragments. If you have a listview added to an activity a single row in the listview can be defined in a second xml file but in this case the single row is not a static Activity, in other words you would not setcontentview on the second xml source. Restated another way an activity is the root of a display screen and it can have one java and one xml file that each can have many nested views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Activity can only have 1 XML layout active at a time, which is decided via `Activity.setContentView(R.layout.file_name)`.

A new View Hierarchy will be inflated when that method is called. You must then find the Views in the View Hierarchy using `Activity.findViewById(R.id.view_id)` to reference the View.

The reason you get `NullPointerException` is because you tried to find a View ID that does not exist in the View Hierarchy. `Activity.findViewById()` will return `null` when that happens. I'm guessing you tried to find a View ID that only exists in one layout but the content view is currently displaying the other layout. You need to merge your two XML files' content into one, then set it as the content view.